# Simple? Increase Field/Box Size

Tags: php

We have a custom CMS on a football website. Within the CMS admin panel is a squad biography section, as shown here:

[image: app.php]

On the above screenshot you will see the ‘Biography’ section highlighted. The code for this section within /app.php is;

```
    <ul class="tr">
        <li class="td1">Biography</li>
        <li class="td2"><input type="text" name="biography" value="<?=$row['biography']; ?>" /></li>
    </ul>
```

I’m trying to make the Biography box bigger as this field will require several paragraphs. Currently, it’s just one character limited row.

I’m also hoping to replicate making the box bigger on the actual outcome too. Screenshot of which is here: [image: index.php]

/index.php contains this code;

```
<ul class="tr">
<li><?=$row['biography']; ?></li>
</ul>
```

Any help as to how I can make the input and output boxes bigger (to accommodate paragraphs rather than one single line) would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could use a `textarea` instead of an `input` field?

Comment: Thanks nico, appreciate the help. Could you please emphasise on that? The opening paragraph explaining I'm a novice was edited out by staff.

Comment: @Dan, thats because the post should go straight into asking the question as only the first few lines are displayed in search results ect. If you want to tell people your a beginner, do it at the end of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using an `input` element try a `textarea`.

```
<textarea name="biography"><?=$row['biography']; ?></textarea>
```

The element is sizeable based on the rows and columns you need.

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Then on your display page you need to replace the newlines (created by the textarea) with `<br />` tags.

```
<li><?= str_replace("<br />", "\n", $row['biography']); ?></li>
```

Comment: Wow, fantastic. Thanks so much Ash. Did the trick superb. Just one last thing - the other fields remember what was entered when you attempt to 'edit' - now, for biography, the information previous entered isn't stored when you attempt to edit, any idea?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it's a while since I wrote html. Check my update. There is no value property, you place the text inbetween the tags. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<textarea>` instead of `<input />` box

Answer (score 0):

This plugin expands a text box to show entire lines when necessary: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettycomments/

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, as the other guy said, it would be best using a textarea, like this;

```
<TEXTAREA Name="content" ROWS=2 COLS=20></TEXTAREA>
```

This way you can select the size of width and length and it would still have all the functionality of a input field.